# Process builder, false positives on multi select pick list

Tags: process-builder, campaign, filters

Using process builder I am channelling new leads to relevant campaigns based on a multi select pick list.  (I know they are not considered best practice but this one is now ingrained in our org beyond removal...)

A lead could be interested in 'Brand name' and / or 'Brand name Europe' both brands have a separate campaign.

I am using a 'contains' filter as opposed to 'equals' as they could have multiple brands and be interested in both.  The problem I am having is that 'Brand name' and 'Brand name Europe' are both ending up in 'Brand names' campaign.

Any suggestions on how to circumvent this with out changing the brand names so that each brand only ends up in its related campaign?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had coffee then just changed my filter and logic now working

Logic: (2 and 3) and( (1 and 4) or (1 and NOT 4))

Filter:

[image]